# Jquery mobile pageshow event does not fire when second page is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have working javascript mobile app which I have been trying to restructure (correctly or incorrectly).  The index.html file contained one page (using `data-role="page"`) with various `<div>` elements that I hide and show depending what the user wants to do.  I thought I could improve the structure by putting each of these `<div>` elements each in their own page (still in the index.html file) using data-role again.  However, the subsequent pages lose their javascript functionality. I have created a very simple index.html file to demonstrate:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
        <INPUT type="button" id="showPageTwo" value="Show Next Page" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="secondPage">
        <INPUT type="button" id="showMainPage" value="Show Main Page" />
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).on("pageshow", "#mainPage", function(e) {   
        alert("Main page");

        $("#showPageTwo").click(function()
        {
            $("#secondPage").show();
            $("#mainPage").hide();      
        });
    });

    $(document).on("pageshow", "#secondPage", function(e) { 
        alert("Second page");

        $("#showMainPage").click(function()
        {
            $("#mainPage").show();
            $("#secondPage").hide();        
        });
    });
</script>    

</body>

</html>
```

Main page displays correctly, the alert is displayed `$("#showPageTwo").click(function()` works.  But none of the javascript runs when secondPage loads.

Additionally when secondPage is shown it does not have the styling from jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css that mainPage has.

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?  (This is when running the app in the Eclipse AVD)

Additionally, I would like to know:

1. Is the way I am trying to restructure my code using `data-role="page"` good or bad practice?  Is there a recommended way to structure "pages" in a mobile app?
2. I also want to put my custom script(s) in their own .js file(s).  Can I only load the script shown in the above code before the `</body>` tag?  Is there any way to load it in the header along with all the other scripts?

Comment: when using _Multi-page model_ place js in head.